# How to delete particular string from paragraph

Tags: iphone

```
Hi Friends, I have a small question,

I have a paragraph of string, now I want to delete some words from that para  

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*bbbbbbbbb*aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
Now, suppose I want to delete the "bbbbbbbb" fromthe above para and I am using the following method

mySpeechText = [[mySpeechText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:strTemp withString:@""] retain];

but this method is replacing the "bbbbbbbb" with blank spaces, ie, "        " and I am getting
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;

and I want aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; without any space. so how can I delete the "bbbbbbbb" rather replacing it.  Thanks-

If I am not clear plz let me know.
```

Comment: stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is working fine for me. I am not getting any space in between the characters.. 

can you update the question with your complete method.

Comment: @Anil: Thanks Anil, Above is the complete method. I am simply replacing the "bbbbbbb" with "" in a particular paragraph but its giving me "        " :-). its strange

Comment: I guess you are correctly removing the strTemp but somehow overlook a pre- or succeeding space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
mySpeechText=[mySpeechText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
               [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"bbbbbbbb"]];
```